# Inserting a textbox (percentage sign) in the gridview that allow user to enter a percentage in the textbox, then populating the cells at the botton

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am stuck with an issue with the Gridview calculation. The scenario is :

I have a Gridview which binded by a resultset which returned from the store procedure. I have programmatically inserted a row of textboxs in the gridview to allow users to enter a percentage. The challenges are : how can I calculate the value based on the percentage and the values in the gridview, then populating the last row with the calculated value?

My code is a bit long, here is a snapshot.

Below code is to bind the grid

```
            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(this.gv1_RowDataBound);



            gv.DataBind();
            gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            gv.Style.Add("CssClass", "bodycopy");
            gv.CssClass = "bodycopy";

            gv.Style.Add("class", "border-right: #99ccff 1px solid; border-top: #000000 1px solid;border-left: #99ccff 1px solid; border-bottom: #99ccff 1px solid");
            gv.Attributes.Add("class", "border-right: #99ccff 1px solid; border-top: #000000 1px solid;border-left: #99ccff 1px solid; border-bottom: #99ccff 1px solid");
            gv.Height = Unit.Pixel(700);
            NewCell.Controls.Add(gv);
            NewCell.Style.Add("CssClass", "bodycopy");

            newRow.Cells.Add(NewCell);
            AssignCellCoordinatesIndividual(gv);
```

Below function is to add the grid to a table which contains a few other grid.

```
private void AssignCellCoordinatesIndividual(GridView gv)
        {


            // Create IDs for Grid
            for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                gv.Rows[i].ID = "r" + i; // Row ID
                for (int ii = 0; ii < gv.Rows[i].Cells.Count; ii++)
                {
                    gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].ID = "c" + ii; // Cell ID

                    //gv.Rows[i].ControlStyle.

                    if ((int)Session["cellCount"] == 0)
                    {
                        if (gv.Rows[i].ID == "r25" || gv.Rows[i].ID == "r26" || gv.Rows[i].ID == "r27")
                        {
                            if (gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].ID != "c0" && gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].ID != "c1" )
                            {

                                User_Controls.txtPercent txtPerc = (User_Controls.txtPercent)LoadControl("~/User_Controls/txtPercent.ascx");
                                TextBox tbox = txtPerc.FindControl("txtPerc") as TextBox;


                                gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].Controls.Add(txtPerc);
                                gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

I have created a usercontrol which contains a textbox, this was dynamically added to the grid in the above code, enabling the user to enter a percentage.
Now I need to calucate the value based on the percentage entered by the user and populating the last row in the gridview.

Does it make any sense?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: when would you like to calculate ? there is a button to click?

Comment: No, when user type into the textbox, on leaving the textbox, it will fill out the cell below with the calculated value. I am using onTextChange event to write the logic. Just unsure how would I be able to loop through the gridview value, and populating the cell below with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

What will you do with 3 rows of percentage textboxes?What does each row of percentage textbox take the percentage of?Is it the percentage of the sum of all the numbers above?Then why do you need 2 more rows filled with percentage textboxes?

I understand you want to add dynamic code because the number of rows from stored procedure may change everytime.I have simplified your code:

```
private void AssignCellCoordinatesIndividual(GridView gv)
    {
        // Create IDs for Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            gv.Rows[i].ID = "r" + i; // Row ID
            for (int ii = 0; ii < gv.Rows[i].Cells.Count; ii++)
            {
                gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].ID = "c" + ii; // Cell ID

                int RowCount=gv.Rows.Count;

                if ((int)Session["cellCount"] == 0)
                {
                    if (i==RowCount+1 || i==RowCount+2 || i==RowCount+3)
                    {
                        if (ii != 0 && ii != 1)
                        {
                            User_Controls.txtPercent txtPerc = (User_Controls.txtPercent)LoadControl("~/User_Controls/txtPercent.ascx");
                            TextBox tbox = txtPerc.FindControl("txtPerc") as TextBox;


                            gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].Controls.Add(txtPerc);
                            gv.Rows[i].Cells[ii].VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

For me to complete the code can you write your formulas for each row so that I can write the Calculate() function

Comment: It is a gridview with 25 rows data returned by the stored precedure. It contains ID, displayname, airvalue, roadvalue, and seavalue. From row number 26, I added three rows of textboxes, allowing users to enter a percentage. This will then calculating row number 29, 30, 31 with a formular. The last row would be the Total value (again with a specific formula). I cant hardcode the row number, because the gridview could return different numbers of rows, it has to be based on the displayname. Its a big headace right now. Thanks if you could help.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for taking time to help. I have decided to do it in Javascript... now I have a new problem :

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help :)

I have decided to do the calculation it in Javascript...

However, I have a new problem.. 

I have a table, the first cell of the table is the gridview which exists on the aspx page. However, from the second cell onwards I dynamcially added more gridviews into the table cell. The maximum cell is 5. I managed to do the calculation in the first gridview/tablecell. But I cant loop through the dynamically added gridview...

var Grid_Table = document.getElementById('<%= gv1.ClientID %>');
The above wont work because it doesnt exist yet...

Comment: Why do you need to do the calculation in Javascript?You can just write server-side C# code to calculate easily.

Comment: Can you remove the "runat=server" from Gridviews and just put them in a form with "runat=server"?Then you can just write `var Grid_Table=document.getElementById('gv1')`

Comment: I have spent 2 days on javascript, its nearly there... I have calculated gv successfully, just from gv1 onwards(the dynamically added gridviews, the script doestn seems to find the gv.clientId....It seems really straight forward thing, somehow I havne't figured out how to do it...

Comment: The table which contains all the gridviews is in the update panel. I see the gv1.clientID from server side, but when I put it in javascript, it returns null... but gv1.ClientID is fine..

Comment: You dont need to write `gv1.ClientId` in javascript just write `var id=document.getElementById('gv1')` and you should have gv1.

Comment: You can keep the value of gv1.ClientID in a hidden box.

Comment: var id=document.getElementById('gv1') doenst work, because it says it doesnt exist in the current context... T

Comment: You can keep the value of gv1.ClientID in a hidden box.`<input type='hidden' id='hdn1' runat='server'/>` and then in the Page_Load() while you add the dynamic gridviews you just write `GridView gv=new GridView(); hdn1.value=gv.clientID;` and then in javascript you can write `var gv1=document.getElementById('hdn1'); var id=gv1.value;`

Comment: Thanks, I jsut gave it a go... however, in the gridview creation bit, I have added this    if (num_Cell == 1)
                {
                    hdn1.Value = gv.ClientID;
                } in javascript  var Grid_Table1 = document.getElementById('<%= hdn1%>'); I can see in the server code its passing a value, however, it says null in javascript, even I typed in the value which i saw from the server side into the javascript, it still couldnt find my gridview, somehow its not the accurate clientID.... :(

Comment: I saved the gv.clientID in the hidden field, however, it isn't the gridview I created... I can't access how many rows in the dynamacially created gridview, its just a hidden field value, doesnt contain anything I created... the clientID is passes through hdn1.Value = gv.ClientID is not the accurate clientID. this is so annoying.

Comment: `var val=document.getElementById('hdn1'); var id=val.value; var gv1=document.getElementById(id);` then you can access gridview1 through gv1.